# how can select unique row using where/having cluse and compare with another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i cant understand how can take unique column (remove duplication) from a table 
which compare with another table data.

in my case

i have two table

[image]

i want to get unique rows from tblproduct after compireing with tblviewer as
[in table viewer first taking viewerid after that taking productid in viewer table afterthat compire with tblproduct.

actualy like that

if i take vieweris=123 two row productid select 12001&11001 after that this tblproduct productid and finaly taking the row from tblproduct which maching.

```
select   * 
from     tblproduct 
where    productid = 
(
    select distinct(productid) 
    from   tblviewer 
    where  viewerid = 123
)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `select distinct`?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: change your `=` to `in`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  You can do a standard `INNER JOIN` to the table to filter the results:

```
Select  Distinct P.*
From    tblProduct  P
Join    tblViewer   V   On  V.ProductId = P.ProductId
Where   V.ViewerId = 123
```

Alternatively, you could use `EXISTS` as well - this eliminates the need to use a `DISTINCT` altogether:

```
Select  *
From    tblProduct  P
Where Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    tblViewer   V
    Where   V.ProductId = P.ProductId
    And     V.ViewerId = 123
)
```

Or, you could also use an `IN`, as suggested by the other answers:

```
Select  * 
From    tblProduct 
Where   ProductId In 
(
    Select  ProductId
    From    tblViewer 
    Where   ViewerId = 123
)
```

Comment: From the performance view this solution has better performance over the other answers

Comment: nice answer @siyual

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to use an IN clause, you will not need to use distinct

```
select   *
from     tblproduct 
where    productid in
(
    select productid 
    from   tblviewer 
    where  viewerid = 123
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but I *think* it is,

```
select   * 
from     tblproduct 
where    productid in
(
    select distinct(productid) 
    from   tblviewer 
)
```